# OpenByUrl throwing error: You do not have permission to call openByUrl (line 39, file "Code")

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script in my Google spreadsheet that opens a Google Doc and returns the text in a certain cell of a table, as follows:

```
function getItemStatus(docUrl) {
   var doc = DocumentApp.openByUrl(docUrl);
   var docBody = doc.getBody();
   var docTbls = docBody.getTables();
   var itmTbl = docTbls[0];
   var itmStatus = itmTbl.getCell(3,1).getText();
   return itmStatus;  
}
```

When I attempt to run the function in my spreadsheet, it returns this error:

> error: You do not have permission to call openByUrl (line 39, file "Code")

If I create another function to call the above function directly it works just fine and returns the value I am after.

```
function testItemGet() {
   var docUrl = ("...");
   itmStr = getItemStatus(docUrl);
   Logger.log("The item's value is " + itmStr)
}
```

Resulting log file:

> [13-07-17 19:27:39:130 EDT] Starting execution
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:387 EDT] DocumentApp.openByUrl([...]) [0.253 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:388 EDT] Document.getBody() [0 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:388 EDT] Body.getTables() [0 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:388 EDT] Table.getCell([3, 1]) [0 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:389 EDT] TableCell.getText() [0 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:389 EDT] Logger.clear() [0 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:389 EDT] Logger.log([The item's value is Deferred , []]) [0 seconds]
>
> [13-07-17 19:27:39:390 EDT] Execution succeeded [0.256 seconds total runtime]

From what I have Googled, as long as I have edit or owner rights to the document I should be able to do this.

I am pretty new to Google Apps Scripting so please be gentle. :)

Thank you ahead of time for your help and patience!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom functions run with limited permissions, and cannot take advantages of services that rely on user credentials, including DocumentApp.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions#permissions

Comment: Thanks Eric. I would think that as long as I have read permissions to a document I should be able to "read" it with my eyes or my code, but I am sure the rules are there for a reason.

Comment: You can perhaps, but custom functions must be able to run for all users viewing the spreadsheet.