# Shared Google sheet users has no permission to call showModelessDialog under installable trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, permissions

I have got a google sheet with a `onEdit` installable trigger calling a bound script.
 In the script it will call `showModelessDialog` to show a dialog and it works fine when I edit the sheet.

The sheet is shared to other users with edit permission, but when they edit the sheet no dialog be showed and got

> "You do not have permission to call showModelessDialog"

Checked the `authMode` is FULL when the script be called by the installable trigger.

Tried to trigger the same script from a custom menu and all users work fine.

May I know why others user cannot call `showModelessDialog` under onEdit installable trigger even `authMode` is FULL and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

`onEdit` is a [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_custom_functions), as discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17727656):

> Custom functions run with limited permissions, and cannot take
>   advantages of services that rely on user credentials, including
>   DocumentApp.

I think that is one of the reason why you are getting that error.

Comment: My function is installable trigger instead of custom function. Besides, the function work for me but just not others shared sheet users.